# jmedia in firefox: returning Flash version when Flash is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

We use the jMedia plugin for jQuery, to detect whether Flash is enabled in the browser. (We have some resources which only work in Flash, and some which have Flash and non-Flash versions).

https://github.com/malsup/media/tree/master

http://jquery.malsup.com/media/

We use it like so:

The jmedia plugin defines a variable _jm which we can call various functions on.

In Chrome, doing this:

```
_jm.detectPluginVersion("flash")
```

will return "undefined" if Flash isn't enabled, and will return the version as a string if it is enabled.

However, in Firefox, even if Flash is blocked, the above code still returns the version.  This is causing problems for us as we use this test to see if Flash is enabled, and if it isn't we can launch a non-Flash alternative (if we have one).  So in Firefox, we're proceeding as if Flash is enabled, but it isn't, which means the resource won't work.

Is there a better way to test if Flash is enabled, with this plugin, which will work cross-browser?

EDIT: digging into this further, the problem doesn't seem limited to jmedia.  I can see the same thing with `navigator`:

chrome, flash disabled:

```
navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]
=> undefined
```

firefox, flash disabled:

```
navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]
=> Plugin { 0: MimeType, 1: MimeType, description: "Shockwave Flash 32.0 r0", filename: "libflashplayer.so", version: "32.0.0.101", name: "Shockwave Flash", length: 2, … }
```